# Create sharepoint document folder using VBA

Tags: excel, office, vba, sharepoint-online

I need to find a way to programmatically, using Excel VBA, create a folder in a Sharepoint Document Library. The Sharepoint Document Library already exist, and it has already one level of folders in it. The new sub-folder to be created will have a specific name which can be passed on by the Excel macro. Is it possible to construct an URL to the Sharepoint site that includes the command to create a sub-folder with a specific name?

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim strDate As String
     Dim strTime As String
     strDate = Date
     strTime = Time
     strDate = Format(Now(), "mmmdd yyyy hh mm")
       Dim strURL As String
       ''Copy and paste the URL of your sharePoint folder where you want to create another folder
       strURL = "http://Your URL"

       strURL = Replace(Replace(strURL, "http:", ""), "/", "\")



      ' MsgBox strDate, vbInformation
     Dim Fld_r As String
     Fld_r = strURL & strDate                
     MsgBox Fld_r, vbInformation
    If Dir(Fld_r, vbDirectory) Then
    MkDir (Fld_r)
    DoEvents
    End If
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the latest version of the Office 365 & Sharepoint.